# Run Katalon Remotely From Jenkins

Tags: selenium, jenkins, katalon-studio

I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to run Katalon tests remotely on CrossBrowserTesting from Jenkins?

Katalon seems great for quickly writing tests, but I need to be able to run tests automatically, remotely, from Jenkins, or it's not actually that helpful to my team.

I had this configuration set up for plain Selenium tests, but I'm not understanding how it would be possible to make this work with Katalon?

In my original Selenium setup, the Selenium tests were added to the app in a /testing/ folder and then Jenkins was able to run those tests in that folder as a build step.

Is there any way to run Katalon tests remotely from Jenkins?

Any insight much appreciated!

Comment: it really depends on what you are trying to achieve. Currently i'm managing a setup with jenkins and Katalon. Jenkins jobs are getting our source code from gitlab and running the console commands of Katalon Test Suites. We use the branches of git to be able to run on diferent releases and we setup additional jobs to create test data automatically. You can check the jenkins integration on katalon site. Additionaly you can check this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bk-brXSCcDw Best wishes

Answer (score 3):

Running Katalon Studio remotely by Jenkins is supported. See [Set Up Katalon/Jenkins](https://www.katalon.com/resources-center/tutorials/jenskins-ci-integration/)